# Bootstrap Page doesn't jump with Accordion tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, accordion

I am using anchor link as

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#product_tab_accordion" class="" href="#tab_static_block_tab_1" aria-expanded="true">Size Guide</a>
```

This opens accordion tab but doesn't jump page to that section.

https://reasonsus.com/men/jackets/monark.html

Comment: bootstrap 3-4 javascript applies on `anchor` tag `onclick` with `e.preventDefault()` inside function this could be the reason.

Comment: Kunal it works fine here https://www.leatherjacketmaster.com/mens-leather-jackets/elegant-men-s-red-leather-jacket-voteporix 

In there page source they have applied a JavaScript code to make it happen but when i copy same code into my files it works fine but moves the position of my tabs

Comment: Maybe bootstrap version differs... Which version you are using ?

Comment: It's same 3.3.5 on both sites i have pasted their code below when i put that same code in my head it works fine but changes the position of my div/section

http://collabedit.com/yneu6